# Cannot pass data from view to controller

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-web

Can anyone explain, how to pass id from view to controller?
[sources](https://github.com/SonicNorg/JavaRushTask)

The problem: when trying to edit existing task, I have a new task added. With new edited name.

```
@RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
public String editTask(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("task", taskService.getTaskById(id));
    model.addAttribute("tasks", taskService.listTasks());

    return "tasks";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTask(@ModelAttribute("task") Task task) {
    if (task.getId() == null) {
        taskService.addTask(task);
    } else {
        taskService.updateTask(task);
    }
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

So, in `addTask()` `task.id` always = `null`, but `task.taskName` is not null. What's wrong with `Long id`?
Maybe, this affects somehow?

```
@Transactional
@Entity(name = "tasks")
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    private String taskName;
```

Comment: You shouldn't experience any problems mapping `Long` types in java. But, what type is `id` in database?

Comment: I dont know, I don't create table by myself. Hibernate does.

Comment: `bigint(20)` shows MySql Workbench

Comment: even if it is `int`, it still is not passed to controller from view.

Comment: problem is not there, `bigint(20)` should be enough for a `long`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved, when I add "=0" to my id declaration:

```
@Entity(name = "tasks")
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id = 0L;
```